# Blk_update_request: I/O error rebooting error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04

My computer with a dual boot of Windows and Ubuntu 20.04 boots to a black screen with this error message:

```
[  647.729444] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40000 action 0x0 
[  647.729482] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000001 
[  647.729498] ata1: SError: {CommWake }
[  647.729516] ata1.00: failed commands: READ DMA EXT
[  647.729534] ata1.00: cmd 25/00:00:20:64:63/00:01:11:00:00/e0 tag 28 dfma 131072 in
[  647.729534]          res 51/40:68:b8:64:63/00:01:11:00:00/f1 Emask 0x9 (media error)
[  647.729590] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  647.729606] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[  647.730346] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 291726520 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
```

Comment: That appears to be an error with the hard drive and does not look like a software error.

Comment: Very likely your hard drive is failing.

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live USB, start the `Disks` app, and show me a screenshot of the SMART Data. Enlarge the window so you capture ALL of the data. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

**Let's see if we can bad block this disk and return it to operation.**

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```